# C# TCP connection works only when using localhost

Tags: c#, networking

I am trying things out with networking in C#, so far i've got the code below, but my problem is that when i connect the Client onto my Server (both running in my laptop) using 127.0.0.1 as the server's IP it works just fine, however when i type in my laptops actual public IP the Client stays there for a while until it throws the error saying the Server didn't respond in time. I've searched for reasons for this and sinse I couldn't find a solution I am posting this here.

Client Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Client
{
    static TcpClient tcpConn = new TcpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Insira como deseja se apresentar: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!tcpConn.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Insira o IP do servidor: ");
                string ip = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Tentando conectar...");
                tcpConn.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ip), 6778);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Conectado");

        Task receiveMsg = new Task(ListenForMessages);
        if (tcpConn.Connected)
            receiveMsg.Start();

        while (tcpConn.Connected)
        {
            Byte[] sentMsgData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{name}: {Console.ReadLine()}");
            tcpConn.GetStream().Write(sentMsgData, 0, sentMsgData.Length);
            tcpConn.GetStream().Flush();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Conexão terminada");

        tcpConn.Close();
    }

    static void ListenForMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] receivedMsgData = new Byte[256];
                int len = tcpConn.GetStream().Read(receivedMsgData, 0, receivedMsgData.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMsgData).Substring(0, len));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Server
{
    static TcpClient tcpConn = new TcpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Insira como deseja se apresentar: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6778);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Esperando conexão...");
        while (!tcpConn.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpConn = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Conectado");

        Task receiveMsg = new Task(ListenForMessages);
        if (tcpConn.Connected)
            receiveMsg.Start();

        while (tcpConn.Connected)
        {
            Byte[] sentMsgData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{name}: {Console.ReadLine()}");
            tcpConn.GetStream().Write(sentMsgData, 0, sentMsgData.Length);
            tcpConn.GetStream().Flush();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Conexão terminada");

        tcpConn.Close();
        listener.Stop();
    }

    static void ListenForMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] receivedMsgData = new Byte[256];
                int len = tcpConn.GetStream().Read(receivedMsgData, 0, receivedMsgData.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMsgData).Substring(0, len));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried allowing both apps on my firewall, testing it using two different machines and tried different ports but none made any difference.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Best practices for configuring Windows Defender Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring)